# Load SQL DB Blob Image Into A Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, base64, blob

I have a database with a field to store blob jpeg image data (ie: FFD8FFE00010...). I can pull the data out with no issue, convert to a byte array and a base64 string. But when the image is displayed, it's less than half the image. Looks like a large bulk of the conversion cuts off the image.

Below is a sample of what I have been using:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../queries/getContactImage.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            iID: pID
        },
        responseType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

            // Loop Through Values And Build String
            if (response.length != 0) {
                $.each(response.aaData, function (index, row) {

                    // CONVERT BLOB TO BYTE[] ARRAY
                    var buffer = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < row.cPHOTO.length / 2 - 1; i++) {
                        var twoByte = row.cPHOTO.substring((i * 2), (i * 2) + 2);
                        buffer.push(parseInt(twoByte, 16));
                    }
                    console.log(buffer);    

                    // CONVERT TO BASE64STRING
                    var binary = '';
                    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                    var len = bytes.byteLength;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                    }
                    var base64String = window.btoa(binary);

                    // THIS ONLY DISPLAYS PART OF THE IMAGE ...
                    $("#lstPicture").append("<img src='data:Image/jpeg;base64," + base64String + "' class='img-responsive pic-bordered'/></img>");

                });
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Contact Image Cannot Be Retrieved.');
        },
    });
```

How do I get the full image to display? Is there a size limit issue?

-Edit-

I tried converting on the server (code below), but the image was getting cut off..

```
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[rdr["cPhoto"].ToString().Length / 2 ]; 
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) { 
    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(rdr["cPhoto"].ToString().Substring(i * 2, 2), 16); 
} 
results.cPHOTO = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: You should base64 encode it on the server, but you should really create a page that displays images given some identifier and not use data uris

Comment: I tried converting on the server (code below), but the image was getting cut off...

Byte[] bytes = new Byte[rdr["cPhoto"].ToString().Length / 2 ];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(rdr["cPhoto"].ToString().Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
}
results.cPHOTO = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

Comment: Are you asking if there's a javascript function that can convert something into base64? Is that what `CONVERTME(..)` is a placeholder for? If so, you should use `btoa(..)` it will convert a string of something into base64. `atob(..)` will do the reverse; it will convert base64 strings into human-readable strings. `btoa('hello') --> "aGVsbG8=" ... atob('aGVsbG8=') --> "hello"`

Comment: @wcarroll Yes. That is where I would want the conversation to take place.

Comment: See above. Does `btoa(..)` help? It's available as a global on the `window` object.

Comment: @wcarroll I think I need to convert it into a Byte Array first, and then use btoa(...) you mentioned above. At lest, that's my process when I tried to build it in C#.

Comment: @wcarroll I've updated the code to include your `bota(...)` suggestion. It works, but only part of the image shows. Is there some kind of size limit you know of?

Comment: @rak11 Off the top of my head, I'm not sure. How large is the inlined base64? Is this something you may want to host on a CDN? I've set base64 limits manually to ~10MB within builds. I'd inline any file below 10MB and host and reference the files that are larger than 10MB.

Comment: @rak11 could you mark my answer as correct if it has helped you? I moved it to a formal answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a function to convert data into base64, then use the `btoa(..)` function. It's globally available through the `window` object.

```
btoa('hello')
// => "aGVsbG8="

atob('aGVsbG8=')
// => "hello"
```

As this example illustrates, `atob(..)` does the reverse of `btoa(..)`. [Here's a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) to the documentation on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-BLOB-Images-from-MySql-Database-in-ASPNet-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Please refere this I think this will help you to get out of it and you can achieve that without using Handler.